# Exception to smart quote substitution for one word

Tags: keyboard, text-input

I have System Preferences|Keyboard enabled for smart quotes. Unfortunately, this tends to turn Hawai‘i into Hawai’i even when I use Option–]. Any suggestion how to get *one* word the way I want? (Not interested in global disable of smart quotes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most correct character for the Hawaiian ʻokina is U+02BB, Modifier Letter Turned Comma.  It is a letter in its own right rather than punctuation.

Using that would hopefully avoid problems that can arise when a punctuation symbol like U+2018 Left Single Quotation Mark is used instead.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ʻOkina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%BBOkina)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little clunky, but you could add a correction from "Hawai‘i" to "Hawai’i" in System Preferences > Keyboard > Text

Comment: I might try that (although, the other way around, the ‘ is correct).